# MVVMパターンを使用して新規レコード追加後のDataGridの表示更新

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

DataGridのItemsSourceをICollectionView型のプロパティにハインディングしており、レコード追加は子ウインドウのパラメータをモデルのメソッドに渡して追加しています。データベースへは問題なく追加できるのですが、追加した際にDataGridの表示が更新方法が解らず悩んでいます。

レコード追加後のDataGridのプロパティは親ウインドウのViewModelにあるため、追加用の子ウインドウのViewModelから変更をしています。

ここは、やはりコードビハインドへのコーディングをしないという縛りで、mvvmパターンの観点から、どのような構成(処理フロー)で組み立てた方がベターなのか、有識者の方のご意見、助言等を頂ければと思い質問してみました。

※フレームワークにLivetを使わせてもらっています。

Answer (score 1):

DataGridにバインドしているリストにINotifyCollectionChangedを実装する事で、追加・削除時にDataGridを更新させる事が可能です。

標準ではObservableCollectionが用意されています。
https://msdn.microsoft.com/ja-jp/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: hiro様
ご回答ありがとうございます。
リンク先などを参照して調整してみたいと思います。

Answer (score 1):

`ICollectionView`は`Refresh`メソッドを呼び出さないと更新されません。

`ICollectionView`の元にした`ObservableCollection`の`CollectionChanged`イベントに、`ICollectionView.Refresh`を呼び出すハンドラを登録する形がよくある実装かと。

Comment: joy1192様　ご回答ありがとうございます。現在はObservableCollectionにバインドしていて、フィルタ等の操作時にGetDefaultViewでViewを取得して操作するという形にしたのですが、Refreshするのが一般的なんですね。元の状態に戻して試してみたいと思います。ありがとうございます。